# How to report value of neighbor in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a list to be collected with the behaviorspace that reports the color of a turtle's neighbor.

```
to-report north-color1
  set north-color []
  foreach sort turtles [the-turtle -> set north-color lput [color] of neighbors4 north-color]
  report north-color
end
```

the "foreach" line is to ensure that the order of the list follows turtle 0, turtle 1, turtle 2, etc in sequential order. However, I want my list to output the color of their neighbor above like [10, 20, 10, 20, 30...] How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there exactly one turtle on each patch? If there are no turtles on the patch above, what do you want reported? If there are multiple turtles on the patch above, which one should be chosen to find the colour?

Comment: It would just report as none. And in my program there is only one turtle per patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete model. Just change the `print north-color-map` to `print north-color` to try out the `foreach` version.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [if random-float 1 < 0.8 [sprout 1]]
  print north-color-map
end

to-report north-color
  let outlist []
  foreach sort-on [who] turtles
  [ this-turtle -> ifelse any? turtles-on [patch-at 0 1] of this-turtle
    [ set outlist lput [color] of one-of turtles-on [patch-at 0 1] of this-turtle outlist ]
    [ set outlist lput "none" outlist ]
  ]
  report outlist
end

to-report north-color-map
  report map
  [ this-turtle -> ifelse-value any? turtles-on [patch-at 0 1] of this-turtle
    [ [color] of one-of turtles-on [patch-at 0 1] of this-turtle ]
    [ "none" ]
  ]
  sort-on [who] turtles
end
```

The `foreach` version is probably easier to understand. It follows fairly closely what you were trying to do - start with an empty list and then run through a list of all the turtles in `who` order (the `sort-on [who] turtles` creates that list) and calculates the colour of the turtle on the north patch. Finding north is done with `patch-at 0 1` but you also have to say north of what - hence `[patch-at 0 1] of this-turtle`. And the `one-of` is to select one turtle from the set of all turtles on that patch - NetLogo can't tell that it will always have one or none so you would get an error essentially saying 'I don't know which turtle to find the colour of'.

The second version uses `map`. It does exactly the same but applies the function to all the members of a list without explicitly constructing the loop. The code is a little simpler because you don't need the empty list and the various `lput` statements. You also need to present everything as a reporter rather than a command. But `map` can be a little trickier to get your head around.

Comment: `sort-on [who] turtles` can be shortened to just `sort turtles`.

Comment: thanks Seth, didn't know that (I never use `who` LOL)